# Only one of the elements are displaying in my component designed to add transition to all of it's children

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, css-transitions

### What I would like to happen:

I would like this Slide in wrapper to have its children slide in from off screen alternating right and left sides. I will also like them to do this with a slight delay so they don't all happen at the same time.

### Current problem:

My code is only displaying the first children `html<p>Element 1</p>` and it doesn't even have a transition currently

#### Main component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import styles from "../styles/SlideInWrapper.module.css"; // Make sure to create this CSS module for styling

const SlideInWrapper = ({ children, delay = 300 }) => {
  const wrapperRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const elements = wrapperRef.current.children;
    const numElements = elements.length;

    const handleTransitionEnd = (index) => {
      const currentElement = elements[index];

      if (index < numElements - 1) {
        const nextIndex = index + 1;
        const nextElement = elements[nextIndex];

        setTimeout(() => {
          nextElement.style.transition = "transform 0.5s ease";
          nextElement.style.transform = "translateX(0)";
        }, delay);
      }
    };

    for (let i = 0; i < numElements; i++) {
      const element = elements[i];
      element.style.transition = "transform 0.5s ease";

      if (i % 2 === 0) {
        element.style.transform = "translateX(-100%)";
      } else {
        element.style.transform = "translateX(100%)";
      }

      element.addEventListener("transitionend", () => handleTransitionEnd(i));
    }

    const initialElement = elements[0];
    initialElement.style.transform = "translateX(0)";

    return () => {
      for (let i = 0; i < numElements; i++) {
        const element = elements[i];
        element.removeEventListener("transitionend", handleTransitionEnd);
      }
    };
  }, [delay]);

  return (
    <div className={styles["slide-in-wrapper"]} ref={wrapperRef}>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

export default SlideInWrapper;
```

#### CSS:

```css
/* Cool slide in wrapper animation */
.slide-in-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.slide-in-wrapper > * {
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
}

.slide-in-wrapper > *:nth-child(odd) {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.slide-in-wrapper > *:nth-child(even) {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.slide-in-wrapper > *:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translateX(0);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

#### How it should look once implemented:

```
      <SlideInWrapper>
        <div>Element 1</div>
        <div>Element 2</div>
        <div>Element 3</div>
        {/* Add more elements here */}
      </SlideInWrapper>
```

Comment: You can try this library - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-animated-list. 
It's just 30kb and simple. Should solve for your use case. But the catch is it requires Material UI i guess.

Comment: Ya my boss hates packages I might be able to get him to go on the animation but not material ui

Comment: I would like it to be somehting I can reuse anyway